# Formatting lists in Telegraph API

Tags: python, html, telegram, telegram-bot, telegraph

Working on a system that includes posting articles on Telegraph via python.
Generally, everything works. But recently I found weird behavior of <ol> and <ul> tags in different browsers. On the mobile version of Telegraph, it works as expected, while everywhere else it is not. Are there any solutions except hardcoding the numbers of lines?
You can check it out yourself here https://telegra.ph/Arthur-Conan-Doyle-Estudio-en-Escarlata-1-09-06 (active as of October 5th, 2021).
The code I am using is below:

```
def update_page(path, title, content, author):
  response = telegraph.edit_page(path, html_content = content, title = title,
                               author_name = author, return_content=True)
  current_path = 'http://telegra.ph/{}'.format(path)
  return current_path 

html = '''
<ol>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ol>
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
'''
title = 'Testing lists'
update_page(test_path, title, html, AUTHOR)
```

Examples of behavior:
[the behavior I need, mobile version of Telegraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNCgv.jpg) and here is
[what I get in Chrome, Firefox and Safari](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DYQ8.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try writing list items in one line like <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li>. This solved it for me.

Comment: that actually worked. thanks! are there any explanations or sources?

Comment: @ЮліяЗавальнюк remember to upvote an useful answer, even more important if it helped you. It really helps to keep people (specially newcomers or low-record users) helping others.